# Every nth column from in matlab to R

Tags: r, matlab, matrix, indexing

I am trying to translate some matlab code to R.

This is the code:

```
v_i = vfull(:,i:ns:k*ns);
```

I think this means take every ns_th column from i to k*ns in the matrix v_i, right?  If I am wrong, can someone please tell me what it means?

Regardless, how would one implement this in R?

Comment: `v_i[ , seq( i , k_ns , by = ns_th ) ]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You interpretation of what Matlab is doing is correct. Here is how to do the equivalent in `R`

```
v_i = vfull[ ,seq(i,(k*ns),ns)]
```